# MySQL: Convert DATE Format While Importing

Tags: mysql, date, import

I have a MySQL script that, on a weekly basis, imports a large dataset (~250,000 records) into a database. This table has 85 data fields, of which 18 are DATETIME fields, For each of these 18 date fields, the script must run the following commands:

```
ALTER TABLE InputTable
  ADD COLUMN EnrollmentDate DATETIME
  AFTER EnrollmentDateRAW;

UPDATE InputTable
  SET EnrollmentDate = STR_TO_DATE(EnrollmentDateRAW, '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p')
  WHERE EnrollmentDate > '';

ALTER TABLE InputTable
  DROP EnrollmentDateRAW;
```

Of course, in an effort to optimize the script, it has a single ALTTER statement that adds all the DATETIME columns, and another single ALTER statement that removes the RAW data fields after conversion.

As you can probably imagine, running the conversion eighteen times on a quarter million records take quite a bit of time. My question is: Is there a way to have the import function convert the date itself, instead of running the conversion after the import?

Answer (score 0):

My advice? Leave both columns in there to avoid painful schema changes if this is a regular thing.

You could also try fixing the data before you import it to begin the correct date format. Ideally this is the [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

If you're pulling in via a CSV, this is usually easy to fix as a pass before doing your `LOAD DATA` step.

You could also stage your data in a temporary table, alter it as necessary, then merge that data into the main set only when all the operations are complete. Altering the schema of a 250K row table isn't that bad. For millions of rows it can be brutal.

Comment: This data is coming into a temporary table, named InputTable, and the data schema changes are quite fast. Yes, the data is coming from a CSV file where the date fields are a completely different nonstandard format. This data comes from a system that is outside my control, so I cannot specify the format used. The UPDATE statement shown above is my way of converting the data after importing it, and it works correctly as is. How do you suggest that I convert the data beforehand?

Comment: Any scripting language that can consume and emit CSV will probably do: Node.js, Ruby, Python, even PHP. Rewrite and then import.